# inconsistency between contamination set up and number of outlier prediction in Sklearn isolation Forest

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

I inspired by this [notebook](https://github.com/elena-sharova/IsolationForest/blob/master/IsolationForest_v0.1.ipynb), and I'm experimenting `IsolationForest` algorithm using `scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1` for anomaly detection context on the **SF** version of [KDDCUP99 dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_kddcup99.html#sklearn.datasets.fetch_kddcup99), including 4 attributes. The data is directly fetched from `sklearn` and after preprocessing (label encoding the categorical feature) passed to the IF algorithm with the default setup.

The full code is as follows:

```py
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score, roc_curve, roc_auc_score, f1_score, precision_recall_curve, auc
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

%matplotlib inline


def byte_decoder(val):
    # decodes byte literals to strings
    
    return val.decode('utf-8')

#Load Dataset KDDCUP99 from sklearn
target = 'target'
sf = datasets.fetch_kddcup99(subset='SF', percent10=False) # you can use percent10=True for convenience sake
dfSF=pd.DataFrame(sf.data, 
                  columns=["duration", "service", "src_bytes", "dst_bytes"])
assert len(dfSF)>0, "SF dataset no loaded."

dfSF[target]=sf.target
anomaly_rateSF = 1.0 - len(dfSF.loc[dfSF[target]==b'normal.'])/len(dfSF)

"SF Anomaly Rate is:"+"{:.1%}".format(anomaly_rateSF)
#'SF Anomaly Rate is: 0.5%'

#Data Processing 
toDecodeSF = ['service']
# apply hot encoding to fields of type string
# convert all abnormal target types to a single anomaly class

dfSF['binary_target'] = [1 if x==b'normal.' else -1 for x in dfSF[target]]
    
leSF = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

for f in toDecodeSF:
    dfSF[f + " (encoded)"] = list(map(byte_decoder, dfSF[f]))
    dfSF[f + " (encoded)"] = leSF.fit_transform(dfSF[f])

for f in toDecodeSF:
  dfSF.drop(f, axis=1, inplace=True)

dfSF.drop(target, axis=1, inplace=True)

#check rate of Anomaly for setting contamination parameter in IF
dfSF["binary_target"].value_counts() / np.sum(dfSF["binary_target"].value_counts())



#data split
X_train_sf, X_test_sf, y_train_sf, y_test_sf = train_test_split(dfSF.drop('binary_target', axis=1), 
                                                                dfSF['binary_target'], 
                                                                test_size=0.33,
                                                                random_state=11,
                                                                stratify=dfSF['binary_target'])

#print(y_test_sf.value_counts())
#1       230899
#-1      1114
#Name: binary_target, dtype: int64

#training IF and predict the outliers/anomalies on test set with 10% contamination:
clfIF = IsolationForest(max_samples="auto",
                        random_state=11,
                        contamination = 0.1,
                        n_estimators=100,
                        n_jobs=-1)

clfIF.fit(X_train_sf, y_train_sf)
y_pred_test = clfIF.predict(X_test_sf)

#print(X_test_sf.shape)
#(232013, 4)

#print(np.unique(y_pred_test, return_counts=True))
#(array([-1,  1]), array([ 23248, 208765])) # instead of labeling 10% of 232013, which is 23201 data outliers/anomalies, It is 23248 !!
```

based on [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix) in the binary case, we can extract true positives, etc as follows:

```py
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test_sf, y_pred_test).ravel()
print("TN: ",tn,"FP: ", fp,"FN: " ,fn,"TP: ", tp)
#TN:  1089 FP:  25 FN:  22159 TP:  208740
```

**Problems**:

- **Problem 1:** I'm wondering why IF predict more than 10% contamination which already set on test set by labelling outlier/anomaly? 23248 instead of 23201 !!
- **Problem 2:** normally `TN` + `FP` should be inlier/normal 230899 and `FN` + `TP` should be equaled 1114 as we counted after data split. I think it is vice versa in my implementation, but I couldn't figure it out and debug it.
- **Problem 3:** is based on the KDDCUP99 dataset [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_kddcup99.html#sklearn.datasets.fetch_kddcup99), and its User guide and my calculation in the following implementation the anomaly rate is *0.5%* and it means if I set `contamination=0.005`, it should give me

[image: img]

Probably I am missing something here, and any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The truth is that the contamination parameter *simply controls the threshold* for the decision function when a scored data point should be considered an outlier. It has no impact on the model itself. It could make sense to use some statistical analysis to get a rough estimate of the contamination.

If you expect a certain number of outliers in your dataset, then you can *use the raw scores to find a threshold* that gives you that number and set the contamination parameter retrospectively when applying the model to new data.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but regardless of the `contamination` rate, which introduces threshold, I'm looking for the reason for **mismatching**  between the number of anomalous labelling in the prediction phase wrt. `contamination` and real percentage it should have been labelled. Consequently, **inconsistency** between the total summation of elements of the `confusion_matrix`, e.g. `fn` and `tp`, should be as size as the number of anomalous data after data split for normal and anomaly classes. (Problem 1 &2)